# How do trench-mounted flak cannons affect enemies?

Tags: iron-brigade

In Iron Brigade, the Flak emplacements will only attack aerial targets. However, there are some machine guns that have the Flak ability, and their descriptions indicate that they are for anti-air use. Is their effectiveness reduced when attacking ground targets? If so, do they deal 0 damage, or just a reduced percentage?

I have been unable to find this information out either in-game or elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, the base flak machine gun does say it does reduced damage to ground enemies, but doesn't say by how much. If anybody knows an approximate value, please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flack machine guns still seem to do full damage on ground targets. Try running an assault mech with 3 scythes on one side and 3 razor of the gods on the other. The scythes will only very slightly outgun the razors against ground targets which is what you would expect given their slightly higher dmg output. Against air targets or small ground targets like knobs the razors will beat the scythes. I think the flack abillity does bonus damage on air units but hits ground units with the normal base damage. I might be wrong and perhaps their is a slight penalty but it doesn't look like it from experience.

One thing I have noticed is that the Razor of the Gods puts out a much larger and more numerous cloud of bullets than the scythes which is odd since they are supposed to have the same rate of fire. I'm not sure what is up with that, but it does make it a lot easier to take out crowds of small targets.

Comment: I think the Flak element puts more into the air so your aim does not have to be as accurate (as "flak" is basically putting shot into the air in the hopes that *something* hits the flying enemy). Machine guns that do not have flak, or other weapons like sniper rifles require good aim to hit the aerial foe.